# Display math should end $$. Missing $ inserted. Bad math environment delimiter

Tags: errors

I have just started writing in Latex and I am getting the same errors constantly. No matter how hard I try to fix these errors, I am breaking some other part. Therefore, I wanted to ask you about my code.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
% preamble
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

A body of mass \(m\) projected 
straight upward with initial velocity \(v_{0}\) satisfies

the differential equation
\begin{equation}
m \frac { d v } { d t } = - k v - m g, \hspace{0.5cm} v(0) = \(v_{0}\)
\end{equation}

where  $g$ = 9.8 $m/sec^{2}$ is the acceleration due to gravity, 
$k > 0$ is a constant  due to the air resistance, 
and \(v\) = $v(t\T)$ is the velocity. The solution is

\begin{equation}
$$
\begin{center}
$v(t\T)$ = $-\frac{ m g }{ k } + 
\left( \(v_{0}\) + $ \frac{ m g }{ k } $  \right)$)  
$e^{- k t / m }.$
\end{center}
$$\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

My first question is about sizes of fonts. Even though I choose 12 pt, the second equation is being smaller than the first one. Also, I couldn't make the second equation centered as in the first one, therefore, I added \begin{center}...\end{center} to second one. Why it is not being centered as in the first equation? Please help me.

Display math should end $$.
Missing $ inserted.
Bad math environment delimiter.

How can I eliminate these problems?

I would be more than appreciated if you could help me.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you should never insert a blank line before a math display, and if the text following the display is part of the same paragraph, don't put a blank line there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}` already specifies that you're setting math content, so don't use `$`..`$`, `$$`..`$$` or `\(`..`\)` inside.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

A body of mass $m$ projected straight upward with initial velocity $v_0$ satisfies the differential equation
\begin{equation}
  m \frac { \mathrm{d} v } { \mathrm{d} t } = - k v - m g, \quad v(0) = v_0
\end{equation}
where  $g = 9.8 m/s^2$ is the acceleration due to gravity, $k > 0$ is a constant due to the air resistance, 
and $v = v(t)$ is the velocity. The solution is
\begin{equation}
  v(t) = -\frac{ m g }{ k } + \left( v_0 + \frac{ m g }{ k } \right) e^{- k t / m }.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am  appreciated to you for your help :)